# Can't connect to telnet altough the service is active

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, telnet

I can't connect to the telnet when I write

```
telnet 192.168.0.1
```

in the console, it says

```
could not open connection to the host, on port 23:connection failed
```

Before asking the question I found a lot of people asking the same question, but without success. For the record I already enabled telnet at the windows features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telnet needs a client and a server component to work. Windows 10 does not come with the server part. You enabled `Telnet Client` in `Windows Features`. To use the Telnet client, you need a server, either a third party solution for Windows 10, another Windows that comes with the Telnet server service, or another device or OS that has a telnet server running.